# UI not updating when a property changes

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

I have the **Contact class** that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
    public class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Contact(Contact contact)
        {
            this.Username = contact.Username;
            this.GUID = contact.GUID;
            this.Msg = contact.Msg;
            this.Ring = contact.Ring;
        }

        private string username;
    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set
        {
            username = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
        }
    }

    public Guid GUID { get; set; }
    public bool Msg { get; set; }

        private bool ring;
        public bool Ring
        {
            get { return ring; }
            set
            {
                ring = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Ring));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

This is the **main page**:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
        {
            public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

            public MainPage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
                Contacts.Add(new Contact("Contact001", Guid.NewGuid(), false, false));
                Contacts.Add(new Contact("Contact002", Guid.NewGuid(), false, false));
            }

            private void AddContactButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Contacts.Add(new Contact("ContactN", Guid.NewGuid(), false, false));
            }

            private void ContactsListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
            {
                Contact clickedContact = (Contact)e.ClickedItem;
                int index = Contacts.IndexOf(clickedContact);
                Contacts.ElementAt(index).Username = "Qwerty";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the **XAML**:

```
<Page
    x:Class="ContactsListBinding.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ContactsListBinding"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:data="using:ContactsListBinding.Models"
    xmlns:namespace="ContactsListBinding.Models">

    <Page.Resources>
        <data:MessageToImageConverter x:Key="MessageToImageConverter" />
        <data:RingToImageConverter x:Key="RingToImageConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Name="AddContactButton" Content="Add Contact" Click="AddContactButton_Click" />
            <CheckBox Name="MessageMeCheckBox" Content="Message me" />
            <CheckBox Name="DeleteMeCheckBox" Content="Delete me" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="ContactsListView" 
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
                          ItemClick="ContactsListView_ItemClick"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Contacts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Contact">
                    <Grid Width="500">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Username}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="15" Height="15" Source="{x:Bind Msg, Converter={StaticResource MessageToImageConverter}}" />
                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="15" Height="15" Source="{x:Bind Ring, Converter={StaticResource RingToImageConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

So, when I click on an item, I change it's Ring property to true. I have debugged and it is changing to true. The only problem is that my UI isn't updating. Any ideas why?

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546360/c-sharp-xaml-ui-not-update-after-change-an-instance-of-observablecollection) and I used it as a guide, but unfortunately I can't get it to work.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint inside `RingToImageConverter.Convert` and confirm whether or not that method is getting called, and completing successfully, when `Ring` changes?

Comment: Not related to your problem but you will want to put in a `if(ring == value) return;` at the top of the set, that way if the new value is equal to the old value it won't raise the event unnecessarily. You also may want to give those things that don't get changed in the view model (Msg, GUID, etc.) a `{get; private set;}` or just a `{get;}` if you are using C# 6, that way it makes it more obvious that the value can't be changed.

Comment: Hmm, it seams that that method is not called. I wonder why is that?

Comment: Try binding it through a `ImageSource` object.

Comment: I changed the code, so it will be simpler if we try to change the username, but the problem is still present.

Comment: Okay guys, I finally got it to work. It seems that the Binding Mode should be set to OneWay, instead of the default OneTime. For example the correct xaml should be: `<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Username, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />` Thank you very much for all your help! :)

Comment: Instead of putting this as a comment post that as an answer and accept it in two days when you can.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ScottChamberlain, will do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay guys, I finally got it to work. It seems that the Binding Mode should be set to OneWay, instead of the default OneTime. For example the correct xaml should be:

`<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Username, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />`

Thank you very much for all your help! :)